# Spring Boot TestContainers Create application from an existing main method in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, testcontainers, spring-boot-testcontainers

I have a Spring Boot application:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val initConfig: SpringApplication.() -> Unit = {
        addInitializers(BeansInitializer())
    }

    runApplication<MyApp>(args = args, init = initConfig)
}
```

I want to run it in dev mode:

```kotlin
object MyAppTest {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        SpringApplication.from (MyApp << how to pass main here?)
            .with(RedisContainerDevMode::class.java)
            .run(*args)
    }
}
```

I don't know how to pass the `main` method into `from`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` function you declared in the first example file is a top level function, so if you want to refer to it in a different file, you need to use syntax like:
`::functionName`

Although in your case, since both functions are called `main`, if you try to put in in there as `::main`, the compiler will assume that you're referring to the static method in the test, and not to the function that initializes your Spring application.

You have 2 options to resolve this:
- change the name of your test function to something else, then import your main function there

```
import your.pkg.path.main

object MyAppTest {
    @JvmStatic
    fun otherMain(args: Array<String>) {
        SpringApplication.from(::main)
                .with(RedisContainerDevMode::class.java)
                .run(*args)
    }
}
```

- or use an [import alias](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/packages.html#imports) to disambiguate the two methods

```
import your.pkg.path.main as springMain

object MyAppTest {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        SpringApplication.from(::springMain)
                .with(RedisContainerDevMode::class.java)
                .run(*args)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chazoshtare answer works, but I found a Kotlin-dedicated way to do it. There is a `fromApplication` extension function in Spring Boot 3.1.1.

```kotlin
import org.springframework.boot.fromApplication


object MyAppTest {
    @JvmStatic
    fun otherMain(args: Array<String>) {
        fromApplication<MyApp>()
                .with(RedisContainerDevMode::class.java)
                .run(*args)
    }
}
```